# How to create .s.PGSQL.5432?

Tags: postgresql

I installed postgresql 9.

By mistake,I deleted the .s.PGSQL.5432. Now i cant able to add server from pgAdmin. I don't have any server in on .

How to create .s.PGSQL.5432?

```
No such file or directory 
Is the server running locally and accepting 
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

, i already tried below code in terminal but not working.

> pg_ctl reload

please someone help us to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

This is the socket file that the server creates on start-up. You need to restart the server, not reload the configuration. Type

`pg_ctl restart`

This will shut-down the running cluster, then start it again.

Comment: How to restart the server?

Comment: It's in my answer: Type `pg_ctl restart`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way it is to let the package manager to fix it for you:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall postgresql-9.1
```

(Supposing that you have 9.1 version installed now.)

Comment: getting same error

Comment: Does the file exists now? How about a full restart?

Comment: I did full restart, sill that file does not exist in that folder

Comment: Ok, let's see if the file is somewhere else... Issue this command: `sudo updatedb && locate .s.PGSQL.5432`. If you see results, then make a softlink from that file to the `/var/run/postgresql/` directory.

Comment: i didn't got any result friend

Comment: if you have that file , please send me a copy of that file /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 to my email id k.arun@outlook.com

Comment: That is a socket file, not a regular one, so it cannot be sent by email. You should try a full reinstall, first: `sudo apt-get purge postgresql-9.1` then `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1`

Comment: Sorry friend: still that file was not created.